# mutate_if multiple conditions along with case_when in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case, mutate

I want to apply the case_when function over those columns who are factors and have only 2 levels and whose names do not contain "kiwi".

This does not work. I can get what I want with other longer approaches but I was wondering if there is any way to do this is an efficient way.

```
librare(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(orange = factor(c(1,1,0,1,0)),
                 apple = factor(c("x", "x", "y", "y", "x")),
                 peach = 1:5,
                 kiwi = factor(c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c")))

df2 <- df %>%
    mutate_if((~ is.factor(.) & nlevels(.) == 2 & str_detect(names(.), "kiwi", negate = TRUE)),
                     ~ dplyr::case_when(.x == 0, "No",
                                        .x == 1 ~ "Yes",
                                        TRUE ~ .x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Operate on a selection of variables](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/scoped.html), it said

> Scoped verbs (`_if`, `_at`, `_all`) have been superseded by the use of `pick()` or `across()` in an existing verb. See `vignette("colwise")` for details.

With `across()`, you can use the [<tidy-select>](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) syntax to keep or drop columns:

- columns which are factors: `where(is.factor)`
- have only 2 levels: `where(~ nlevels(.x) == 2)`
- columns whose names do not contain "kiwi": `!contains("kiwi")`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(~ is.factor(.x) & nlevels(.x) == 2) & !contains("kiwi"),
                ~ case_when(.x == 0 ~ "No",
                            .x == 1 ~ "Yes",
                            TRUE ~ .x)))
```